# HTML/JavaScript: calling a function with drop-down options?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for calling a Javascript function when a certain option is selected in an HTML drop-down menu.

This is the HTML segment of my menu:

```
<select id="change_chart" onChange="drawStuff()">
    <option value="1" selected>livejournal</option>
    <option value="2">librarybooks</option>
    <option value="3">sunspots</option>
</select>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
function drawStuff() {

    var menu = document.getElementById("change_chart");

    var selected = menu.addEventListener("change", generateData);

    function generateData(event){
            if (menu.value == '1') {
                //do something
            }
            else if (menu.value == '2') {
                //do something
            }
            else if (menu.value == '3') {
                //do something
            }
        };
};
```

I'm new to event-driven programming so I have no idea if any of this is right. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So one thing I want to mention here, is that you're adding a new event listener everytime the `drawStuff` function runs. So each time you change the input, you'll register a new event listener. This will slow down your site if someone were to keep changing the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work properly because the inline `onChange="drawStuff()"` is defining an event handler that calls that function. So far, so good. But then `drawStuff()` itself defines a second event handler and attaches it with `addEventListener()`, so the `generateData()` part won't run until the *second* change event  on that element. (Then on the third change event it would attach another handler, etc.) You want one method or the other, not both:

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("change_chart");
menu.addEventListener("change", generateData);

function generateData(event) {
  if (menu.value == '1') {
    alert(1);
  } else if (menu.value == '2') {
    alert(2);
  } else if (menu.value == '3') {
    alert(3);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="change_chart">
    <option value="1" selected>livejournal</option>
    <option value="2">librarybooks</option>
    <option value="3">sunspots</option>
</select>
```

If you do it as shown above, the JavaScript would need to be included in a `<script>` element that is *after* the `<select>` element, and/or wrapped in a `DOMContentReady` on `window.onload` handler.

Here's how it should look if you want to use the inline `onChange` handler in your HTML - note that it passes `this` as an argument to the function, then within the function that is a reference to the element:

```js
function drawStuff(menu) {
  if (menu.value == '1') {
    //do something
    alert(1)
  } else if (menu.value == '2') {
    //do something
    alert(2)
  } else if (menu.value == '3') {
    //do something
    alert(3)
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="change_chart" onchange="drawStuff(this)">
    <option value="1" selected>livejournal</option>
    <option value="2">librarybooks</option>
    <option value="3">sunspots</option>
</select>
```

P.S. The first way, with `addEventListener()`, is generally the preferred way to do it these days.

Comment: That makes so much more sense. Thanks!